# Automatic block threshold ips on linux server

Tags: linux, webserver

What is recommended way to auto temporary block the IP addresses that have excessive hits on my Linux Server? Let's say I have IP addresses that have 6154 hits per day and I want to auto block such IPs that exceeds 1000 hits per day temporary for specified time interval (or what is standard time interval?).

Also I should be available to add white list IP addresses that Shouldn't be block such as Google bot.

Comment: Are you asking about generic connections, or are you running Apache or nginx, for example, and are talking specifically about web site hits?

Comment: Generic http connection, hackers use to dump website content or sometimes unkown bots crawling website and slow down server

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `fail2ban`. The idea of this tool is that it scans logfiles for a particular pattern (e.g., `password incorrect from ip X.X.X.X`), counts matches, and updates firewall rules based on those counts.

While the tool was meant for blocking authentication failures, it is flexible enough that you should be able to use it for this kind of stuff, too

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Apache, you might want to look into [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/).

It's an Apache 2 module (Apache 2.2 recommended) which allows you to protect web sites from a range of different attacks.  It's essentially, a Web Application Firewall (WAF).

You can use mod_security in combination with `fail2ban` to block connections at the IP level (using iptables) rather than at the application level (i.e. at the web server level).

Comment: If I don't have Apache, I can use only fail2ban for this purpose?

Comment: It depends on what web server you *are* using.